# How to call last unit in data.frame without using length()?

Tags: r

Usually when I want to define the last unknown unit number when calling a series I would use;

```
z <- length(data)

mean(data[3:z])
```

However isn't there a much simpler way to define the last unit in the same statement without having to call and define length as a separate variable? Like a special symbol to imply the last unit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mean(data[3:length(data)])` should work if you don't want an exra variable..?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a shortcut for that but instead of selecting from 3 to length, you can also remove first 2 elements which can be done using indexing :

```
data[-(1:2)]
```

Or using `tail`

```
tail(data, -2)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
 data[tail(names(data), -2)]
```